# Can not connect to Kafka outside container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to implement blackbox testing of my app. So I created compose file

```
version: '3.4'
services:  
  kafka:
    image: "spotify/kafka"
    environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=kafka
      - ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.2
  app:
    build: ./blackbox
    image: app    
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.17.0.4
networks:
  testing_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.17.0.0/16"
```

It works fine, application inside app container can connect to kafka using kafka:9092 host.
But app is consumer, and producer is located outside of containers. When I try to populate data outside containers I get error:

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer] WARN o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer] Error connecting to node kafka:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
```

I could add "kafka" host to hosts file and it maybe will work, but I have to run this scenario not only at local machine but at CI\CD

I tried to set ADVERTISED_HOST=172.17.0.2. It doesn't work as well.

I can not edit any kafka config files, I can only use docker-compose file

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

UPD.

Solved this issue using dirty hack. For windows for sure, for other systems need to check Docker adds following host to hosts file: kubernetes.docker.internal:127.0.0.1 In that case inside container I use

```
kafka:
    image: "spotify/kafka"
    environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=kubernetes.docker.internal
      - ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.102
    extra_hosts:
      - "kubernetes.docker.internal:172.16.238.102"
```

And kafka broker works for outside application because kubernetes.docker.internal is known host

Comment: spotify image is old; don't use it

Comment: Please don't add answers in the question itself. Rather post it as an answer. Since this question is closed, you can add it to the duplicate target mentioned on the top of the post. This helps to keep information centralised and findable.

Comment: Proposed solution works for this particular case.